# Add Unsubscribe Link To EE Emails

Tags: ee2, email, html-email, mailinglist

I am using the built-in mailing list activation template on an EE website I am working on and would like to include an unsubscribe link at the bottom of the email.

I have tried adding the tag `{unsubscribe_url}` to the bottom, but it does not seem that this tag is being parsed correctly.

Is there another way of achieving this?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
<td height="50" align="middle">You are receiving this message because you have signed up to receive the newsletter. To unsubscribe, please click <a href="{unsubscribe_url}" style="color:#729134;">here</a></td>
```

Comment: can you elaborate on this by showing your email template code since {unsubscribe_url} should generate a link if you are using the built in mailing module.

Comment: Please see code added

Comment: Can you output the value of `{unsubscribe_url}` for us please? it should be an ACTion link, ie link to the index of your site with the query string `?ACT=#` where # is the action number for `unsubscribe` in the `exp_actions` table.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the standard MailingList module and you just can't get `{unsubscribe_url}` to work, you can create the unsubscribe URL yourself with a little PHP snippet:

```
<?php

  //fetch the action ID
  $actionID = ee()->functions->fetch_action_id('Mailinglist','unsubscribe');

  //was it a valid ACT ID? If not the mailing list is probably not installed
  $unsubUrl = "";
  if ( !empty($actionID) && isnumeric($actionID) && intval($actionID) == $actionID ) {
      //create the URL
      $unsubUrl = ee()->functions->fetch_site_index(true) . '?ACT=' . $actionID;
  } else {
      //optionally handle issues here, we have no action!
  }

  //Display the link
  if ( !empty($unsubUrl) ){ ?>

    <a href="<?php echo $unsubUrl; ?>" title="Unsubscribe">Unsubscribe</a>

  <?php }
?>
```

**Ammendum**
Of course, if you're using the standard template you can't use PHP as above...

I've copied the default template as it is supplied by the module (fresh install) and I notice a couple of little things in your snippet. Here's the default template:

```
{message_text}

To remove your email from this mailing list, click here:
{if html_email}<a href=\"{unsubscribe_url}\">{unsubscribe_url}</a>{/if}
{if plain_email}{unsubscribe_url}{/if}
```

I notice that the quotes are all escaped in the default template, looking at the 3rd line (`{if html_email}...`) you'll see all the quotes are escaped `\"`.

Could you try the example with the escaped quotes please? Also as I mentioned can you confirm the unsubscribe action is set up correctly (i.e. is present in `exp_actions`)?

Comment: MY bad, read the question... You're using the built in template so PHP code is not allowed. I have edited my answer...